# php sleep or usleep freezes out entire server

Tags: cron, sleep, freeze

I have a big table in a data base which is updated almost every second. I want to query this table every 5 second to get the latest entries (live streaming).

I can't query data base for each visitor (ajax post request every 5 seconds) because mysql will die. This is why I need to cache a file. I'm writing data in a file than a visitor with javascript will open/read/close the file every 5 second.

Everything works fine, but I'm having trouble with cronjob + sleep.

In cpanel I can't set 5 sec cronjobs, this is why I'm running a for() with 12 cycles within 5 sec sleep.

```
for($i = 0; $i <12; $i++){
   mysql_query() /// writing in file, etc.

   sleep(5);
}
```

The problem is this is freezing out the entire server for 60 seconds. Not only the cronjob php file, the entire web page is timed out.

What should I do? Am I doing it right?

Comment: Do you close the file before starting the sleep?

Answer (score 0):

Note there is no guarantee that the code you posted is going to run in precisely 60 seconds. In fact, that code is going to run in AT LEAST 60 seconds. I'm not sure if that matters, but this means there's going to be a period of overlap between two or more instances of this script running via cron.

Depending on your queries and the way you're handling your database and cache reads/writes, you could be creating a database lock or deadlock situation, which in turn could cause the script to run long. Running long means it's potentially eating up database/server resources. This situation is what I'm leaning towards as the cause for your web page timeout. I'd need more details regarding your queries and database/cache file.